# what is %<number>f doing in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

If I use a conversion specifier like `%.2f` to print a floating point number, it limits the floating point to 2 decimal places when it's printed.

But using a formation like `%2f` to a float doesn't seem to be doing anything, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you read the man page? There, it's described as the *minimum field width* (hint: try using a larger number, such as 15, if you want to see much difference).

Comment: Why is [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) not enough to answer your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as its answer is a [trivial documentation lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: You're missing that `%2f` says simultaneously 'at least two characters of output' and '6 decimal places of output' (by default, because there was no `.n` to override it).  And, since it must print 7 characters, the 'minimum of 2' is meaningless.  Increase 2 to 20 and you'd see an effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ***minimum** field width*. Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [...] minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters than the
>   field width, it is padded with spaces (by default) on the left (or right, if the left
>   adjustment flag, described later, has been given) to the field width. [....]

I ran a test program, just to understand

```
printf("%10f\n", 20.56);
printf("%f\n", 20.56);
```

the output is

```
 20.560000
20.560000
```

---

For a better understanding:

```
printf("%06.2f\n", 2.56);  // zero padding, instead of space, limited the precision
printf("%0.2f\n", 2.56);   // to be only two digits, so, total width to be printed 
                           // is 4, and in first case, we take the minimum width to be 6
                           // so, on left, 2 digit padding should be there
```

result:

```
002.56
2.56
```